# What can be a good way to call network class other than an activity in android?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-activity, network-programming

I have created a network client app (using Retrofit) where I call for network request and response in the activity. I learned that it is a bad practice. If anyone can suggest that what can be a good design pattern that I can follow to do such an operation?

Comment: do you mean a repository ? `I learned that it is a bad practice.` what are you doing which is considered bad practice ? could you maybe include some code

Comment: use Repository pattern for API calls using DI [SampleProject](https://github.com/GolnazTorabi/CleanArchitecture)

Comment: @a_local_nobody I mean calling network operation in an activity. Network operation is like fetching some information from an API. As activity is joined with UI, maybe a good software design pattern does not follow this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Start if you have to create an app from scratch, possibly try to follow one architecture since you are looking for network calls, [image]

You can Use MVVM for best practice and it also handle the api request in best way possible As you can see from figure,
This architecture, basically separates the view(UI) from view Model(logic of view)

It's up to you how you want to develop the app, means you can skip the repository and handle the network calls in view models or else you can create a single repository class and place all the network related stuffs i.e: network call and similar stuff.

reference tutorial : https://learntodroid.com/consuming-a-rest-api-using-retrofit2-with-the-mvvm-pattern-in-android/

Comment: It will be useful I guess. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a RetrofitClient Class like this**

```
    public class RetrofitClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "YOUR BASE URL HERE";
    public static RetrofitClient mInstance;

    private Retrofit retrofit;

    public static RetrofitClient getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null)
            mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
        return mInstance;
    }

    private RetrofitClient() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public ApiInterface getApiInterface() {
        return retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    }

    public interface ApiInterface {
        @GET("api_name_here")
        Call<ResponseBody> methodName();
    }
}
```

**Repository class**

```
public class MyRepository {
        private static MyRepository mInstance;

        public static MyRepository getInstance() {
            if (mInstance == null)
                mInstance = new MyRepository();
            return mInstance;
        }

        private MyRepository(){

        }

        private LiveData<T> getData(){
            MutableLiveData<T> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

            RetrofitClient.getInstance()
                    .getApiInterface()
                    .methodName()
                    .enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<T> call, @NonNull Response<T> response) {
                            liveData.setValue(response.body());

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<T> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                   //  handleFailure
                }
            });

            return liveData;

        }
}
```

**ViewModel Class**

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel{
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    public MyViewModel(){
        myRepository = MyRepository.getInstance();
    }

    public LiveData<T> getData(){
        return myRepository.getData();
    }
}
```

**Then in your Activity or fragment**

```
    MyViewModel myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
    myViewModel.getData().observe(this, new Observer<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(T t) {
            // handle your data here...
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is how I follow MVVM pattern. If you have any question, please let me know.